# Create a list of Items with a clickable "detail" in front

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, grid

Im trying to create a List of Items(two columns),first columns are my items and second is clickable DETAIL,so when i click on the detail i want to open a another grid binding all the respective details,any idea how can create the first grid using Kendo or anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kendo UI supports both parent-child grids and with custom templates for displaying cell data / action buttons, which sounds like the sort of thing you are looking for. Plus you can set the data of the first grid manually or from an api call.

The grid is available in jQuery and Angular variants and the Kendo demo site is a pretty good place to get started.

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/detailtemplate